# Are there any good online tutorials to TDD for an experienced programmer who is new to testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I'm working with a Python development team who is experienced with programming in Python, but is just now trying to pick up TDD.  Since I have some experience working with TDD myself, I've been asked to give a presentation on it.  Mainly, I'm just wanting to see articles on this so that I can see how other people are teaching TDD and get some ideas for material to put in my presentation.

Preferably, I'd like the intro to be for Python, but any language will do as long as the examples are easy to read and the concepts transfer to Python easily.

Comment: I think your best bet is to pair with members of the team, saying, "today let's take a test-first approach to solving today's problem, so you'll get a feel for TDD."  Next best, in the presentation, just work a modest example.  Experiencing it is best; seeing it, second-best.  Hearing about it, not so good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One suggestion I'd make is to start a [coding Dojo](http://codingdojo.org/) group. It helps to start TDD from scratch with a group, with most of recommended best-practices and focus on TDD.

Its basic ideas is to take a simple challenge (like a program that transforms roman algarisms strings into ints), and start to code it, starting from simple inputs, and coding only when there's a test failing. It's not the focus of this to end the problem, but to start making it the right way.

Here's another [link](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~gpollice/Dojo.html) about it, from which I retrieved the following part:

- There is a coding challenge that is announced beforehand.
- There is a room with one computer attached to video screen.
- The presenter explains the coding challenge and starts the coding. The presenter may or may not choose to have a co-pilot. If this is a Randori session, a co-pilot is usually assigned so that when the switch occurs, the co-pilot takes over for the coder.
- One half of the pair is changed every 5 minutes if the session is Randori.
- The coder should continuously explain what she or he is doing.
- The coder should stop when someone from the audience falls off the sled (has a question about understanding what the pair is doing) -- and only continue when that someone is back on track again.
- **All coders use TDD (Test-Driven Development).**
- All produced code will be made publicly available using the Eclipse Common Public License.
- The programming language to be used is announced in advance per session.

Comment: I really like this idea.  I'll try it out.

Comment: +1, I wish I'd known about these earlier in my TDD journey. Here's a book I'm using to help me run dojos: https://leanpub.com/codingdojohandbook

Answer (score 4):

I was very pleased with the two-part article "Test Driven Development in Python" on O'Reilly's site:

http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2004/12/02/tdd_pyunit.html - [waybackmachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140804160053/http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2004/12/02/tdd_pyunit.html)

http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2005/02/03/tdd_pyunit2.html - [waybackmachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140804142354/http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2005/02/03/tdd_pyunit2.html) [2/3](https://web.archive.org/web/20140215194252/http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2005/02/03/tdd_pyunit2.html?page=2) and [3/3](https://web.archive.org/web/20131127001859/http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2005/02/03/tdd_pyunit2.html?page=3)

These really cleared up how to use Python's unittest module for TDD, as well as giving me a good dose of the TDD mindset.

Answer (score 3):

[Kent Beck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13842/kent-beck)'s [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) gives some examples in Java and some in Python (to be honest, Kent doesn't strike me as a superstar in either language, judging from the example code in this book... but he *definitely* comes across as a superstar in TDD &c -- as well he should, given he's basically invented it as well as extreme programming, see his [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_Beck) entry).

Comment: I have to say I was kind of underwhelmed by that book. Many of the things he suggested doing seem downright harmful to me. For example, he advocates making the code return exactly what the test expected (ie: lying to the test), and then calls the act of fixing the code so that it actually works in other cases refactoring. This is so wrong on so many levels that I found it hard to take the rest of the book seriously.

Answer (score 1):

Not in python but this is a good intro by jp boodhoo

http://www.bestechvideos.com/2008/06/28/dnrtv-show-10-jean-paul-boodhoo-on-test-driven-development-part-1-of-2

Answer (score 1):

I think that the chapters covering testing in [Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython.net/unit_testing/index.html) are pretty good.  They cover building a basic program from scratch using TDD.

Answer (score 0):

[Getting Started with Tdd in Java using Eclipse by Brett L. Schuchert](http://vimeo.com/10569751)

Is a set of screencasts about TDD in Java and in C#. It is starting from the scratch and teaching basics.

Answer (score 0):

I started unit testing a handful of years ago, and I've read quite a few on it since my initial book.
However, my initial was "Test Driven" by Lasse.
For me, the author made it simple to understand.
Perhaps you could pull some info from it for your teaching.

And btw, I've taught TDD as well.
I have found that ensuring the audience understands how to use unit tests before going into TDD to be quite handy.

Good luck!  :-)