# TDD Implementing Step Definitions derived from Behave (Python)

Tags: python, tdd, python-behave

Where do I put Behave's implementation code so that it will not fail Behave's tests? Further do I need to import anything or put any code in so the code I write is linked to the feature file.

Here an excerpt from my feature file `\steps\main.feature` ...

```
Feature: Main program
    Program allows users to create create and view development logs 

Scenario: User requests development logs for a particular user
    Given user has requested development logs for a given user
    Then the development logs for that user will show
```

And here are the implementation suggestions (that come from running Behave):

```
@given(u'user has requested development logs for a given user')
def step_impl(context):
    raise NotImplementedError(u'STEP: Given user has requested development logs for a given user')

@then(u'the development logs for that user will show')
def step_impl(context):
    raise NotImplementedError(u'STEP: Then the development logs for that user will show')
```

I realise this is really basic information but nothing in the documentation covers this and although there are lots of tutorial on Google none of them cover this. I assume it is just too basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to this was threefold:

1. I was raising a not implemented error so the test failed.
2. At the top of my Python file I needed to include `from behave import *`.
3. My Python file needed to be a directory called `steps`.

I worked this out myself by trial and error after looking at the answer to [Python TDD directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859832/python-tdd-directory-structure?rq=1).